# Visualforce page redirects to sandbox org

Tags: visualforce, redirect

My visualforce page opens in the sandbox it was created in, even when I'm in a different sandbox.

I created a page and controller, which worked fine, in sandbox (dev1). I deployed it to a staging sandbox (staging1) and when I access it I'm redirected to dev1, whatever I do, and regardless of whether I'm logged in at the time.

This happens when I access the page by:

- Using the custom URL button I created.
- Clicking preview on the page screen in setup.
- Adding the page directly in the URL.

What's going on?

Comment: can you share your code? How does that work in anonymous mode?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes! Was in Firefox, opened Chrome and internet explorer and it worked in both, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have multiple sessions going and they're colliding. Log out of any sandbox, and then make sure you're only logged in to one at a time. You can use incognito windows, other browsers, or plugins to make sure you keep your sessions clean.